# Writing scheme function to double an element in a list given a character to search for

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

My goal is to write a function named (double ALIST ELEM) that accepts a list of elements and returns that list where every occurrence of ELEM (any scheme value) has been replaced by a sequence of two ELEM's. The replacement will not occur within nested lists.

For example, if I were to call

```
(double '(a b c) 'c)
```

It would return

```
'(a b c c)
```

This is the code that I have so far

```
(define (double x y)
  (cond ((null? x) '())
    ((not(equal? (car x) y)) (double (cdr x) y))
      (else (append (list (car x)) (append x (double (cdr x) y))))))
```

If we take the previous example and replace c with a, I get the correct output. However, if I run the example above I get just a list containing '(c c). I have tried many different ways of writing this and I always seem to get this output. I am entirely unsure of what I am doing wrong in this case.

Ok, so I found one error (at least I think), to keep the previous elements in the list if the character I am looking for is not found, but now I am stuck on the else statement and what I need to put in there to add the element in that position again and recall the function. These are the updated changes

```
(define (double x y)
  (cond ((null? x) '())
    ((not(equal? (car x) y)) (append (list (car x)) (double (cdr x) y)))
      (else <insert-code-here>)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event the element matches `y`, you want to `cons` `y` on twice

otherwise, just re-`cons` the list by recursing with the tail

```
(define (double xs y)
  (cond ((null? xs) '())
        ((equal? y (car xs)) (cons y (cons y (double (cdr xs) y))))
        (else (cons (car xs) (double (cdr xs) y)))))

(double '(a b c a b c a b c) 'c)
;; => '(a b c c a b c c a b c c)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think to use the element I was looking for to add on to the list using cons. Thank you. I was so dead bent on using append in some way to solve the problem.

Comment: You could also do `(cons (car xs) (cons (car xs) (double (cdr xs) y)))` – but since `y` is equal to `(car xs)` it just reads a little nicer as `y` ^_^

Comment: Yeah that's true -.- , I guess the part of me not thinking to even use cons to solve the problem still holds true though. Thank you.

Comment: `(append (list y y) (double (cdr xs) y))` works too but it is less efficient than the simple `cons` in this case ^_^

Comment: Wow, haha. Wrapping my head around scheme is a struggle sometimes.